# How can I determine the input area size of a TEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

It's easy to get the outer dimensions of a TEdit control, but that includes a bevel (or the frame, depending on whether Ctrl3d is true or not). I would like to find out the dimension and position of the white input area only of a TEdit.

I tried TEdit.ClientRect, but it seems to give only the correct size if Ctrl3D is true. I still have to add two pixels to Left and Top to adjust for the bevel.

If Ctrl3D is false, the size is too large by two pixes and the Left / Top offset must be increased by one.

Is there any way to get the correct size and position of this area, e.g. using a Windows API function?

Comment: I'm curious as to what motivates the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My motivation was this question stackoverflow.com/q/31549854/49925 and the fact that it requires themes to be enabled to work. I don't want to enable themes for some programs because it wreaks havoc with custom highlighting. But the cue for edit fields is nice and I thought that it would be relatively easy to emulate it with a panel inside the edit area

Answer (score 3):

On Vista and higher, you can use [`EM_GETRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message:

```
function GetEditRect(Edit: TCustomEdit): TRect;
begin
  SendMessage(Edit.Handle, EM_GETRECT, 0, LPARAM(@Result));
end;
```

Unfortunately:

> Under certain conditions, `EM_GETRECT` might not return the exact values
>   that `EM_SETRECT` or `EM_SETRECTNP` set—it will be approximately correct,
>   but it can be off by a few pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but it doesn't work reliably. I haven't yet determined under which circumstances it fails but when playing with the various settings for Border, Bevel and Ctrl3D I got wrong values.